# .Net Dependency Injection: Can a Transient class depend on a Scoped class? And are there any gotchas?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

.Net Core native Dependency Injection: Can a Transient class depend on a Scoped class? And are there any gotchas? If there are useful cases for that, what are some of those cases (being specific with details). And what are the pros and cons of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely. With no gotchas.**

> 1. Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to every injection.
> 2. Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests.

Which means that your scoped objects which are created in every request can be injected with a transient class which will be newly created just for that specific injection.

An example use case would be:

1. You have a custom made class implementing `ICollection`, which utilizes a randomizer seeded by current timestamp when it was created and you written those logic in its constructor.
2. You have a scoped service class injected into a controller. This service depend on previous class to do some logic.
3. Every time the former class was injected into the latter class, it will be newly created, seeded with current timestamp at its creation.

Comment: You answered the exact opposite of what the question is asking.